# @property doesn't store value in DB

Tags: django, django-models

My model is like this:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False,blank=False)
    total = models.FloatField(null=False,blank=False)

    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.quantity * self.product.price
```

The total appears in my admin dashboard but when I inspect the db from the shell I don't get the total value, I get the other values:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 42, 'product_id': 11, 'quantity': 2}]>
```

Expected output:

```
<QuerySet [{'id': 42, 'product_id': 11, 'quantity': 2, 'total': 29.00}]>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django models save data once the save() method execuate.

Try this, it works very well. It's a best practice

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False,blank=False)
    total = models.FloatField(null=False,blank=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total =  self.quantity * self.product.price
        super(Cart, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `@property` decorator is a Python method, your database knows nothing about it. The property will still work in Python code and Django templates, but you won't be able to use DB operations against it like other fields (e.g. using `.filter` or `.values` with `total`).

If you need to query against the total, what you probably want is to use [annotations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/) instead.

Just omit the `total` from your model altogether and you can annotate your queries to have the DB calculate the total on-the-fly:

```py
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper, F

queryset = Cart.objects.annotate(
    total=ExpressionWrapper(
        F("quantity") * F("product__price"), output_field=models.FloatField()
    )
)
for cart in queryset:
    print(cart.total)
```

`ExpressionWrapper` is used to define the `output_field` (so Django knows what type the result should be) which is needed when multiplying integerfields by floatfields.

If you want queries to *always* return the annotated total, you can override the model's default manager.

```py
class CartManager(models.Manager):
    def with_total(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        return qs.annotate(
            total=ExpressionWrapper(
                F("quantity") * F("product__price"), output_field=models.FloatField()
            )
        )

    def get_queryset(self):  # override the default queryset
        return self.with_total()


class Cart(models.Model):
    objects = CartManager()  # override the default manager
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
```

Comment: Nice that's what so Helpful. Edit this out `output_field=models.FloatField()`

Comment: @Jackson edited the `()` in, thanks for the correction! If this answers your question, consider upvoting/accepting it :-)

Answer (score 0):

`@property`  decorator is not for saving data in DB.
What the `@property` decorator does is declare that it can be accessed as a regular property.

This means you can call `total` as if it were a member your model instead of a function, so like this:

```
total = cart.total  #in views
{{ cart.total }}    #in templates
```

instead of

```
total = cart.total()  #in views
{{ cart.total() }}    #in templates
```

for more details on `property`, you can refer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/glossary/#:%7E:text=application-specific%20settings.-,property,-Also%20known%20as)

If you still want to store the value in total field, then save it to database instead of returning it in the method.

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False,blank=False)
    total = models.FloatField(null=False,blank=False)
    
    @property
    def save_total(self):
        total = self.quantity * self.product.price
        self.total = total
        return total
```

or

you can save the data to total in your views, while your cart is saved in view.py